# word-break within words

Tags: html, css

I have this html

```
<div class="externalWidth">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="element">this_is_a_really_long_text_without_spaces</div>
        <div class="element noWrap">:-)</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="externalWidth">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="element ">this is a really long text without spaces</div>
        <div class="element noWrap">:-)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.externalWidth { width: 200px; }
.container { margin-bottom:10px; display:inline-table; height:40px; width:100%; }
.element { display:table-cell; }
.noWrap { white-space:nowrap; }
```

I have made an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurumusch/XUqSU/6/) to demonstrate it. The texts in both `.element`s are read from a server and bound via [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). I want this to look as follows:

- the second `.element` should have as much space as it needs
- the first `.element`should have the remaining space. It should break into multiple lines if possible.

Everything works fine but long words causes the whole table to expand. Is it possible to break within words if necessary?

I've also tried `table-layout:fixed;` but that made two `100px` colums.

Edit: Thanks. `word-break: break-all;` did exactly what I needed.

Comment: Have you tried `word-break: break-all;`?

Comment: prefer using % for width rather than px

Comment: What about soft hyphens?

Comment: Good question, im wondering this aswell and still havent figured a way for it. :-)

Comment: Or soft hyphens: `word-break: hyphenate:`...

Comment: There are many existing questions about the same basic issue. What makes this “not-a-real-question” is that you do not indicate or even suggest what the *real* textual content is. The applicability of answers heavily depends on that. And you need to decide what the acceptable break points are and whether it should be simple breaks or hyphenation (with “-” introduced at end of line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS `word-break` Property

try this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/apalof/1)**

Comment: I didn't downvote it myself, but there is a problem with `word-break: all;`; it wraps completely indiscriminately, usually breaking inside words. Even if there are better places to break, like spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could "pre-process" your content (on the server or in JS if you can't do this on the server) to inject a soft-hyphen into very long words.  `&shy;` is the entity to use, and this will allow modern browsers to break at the soft-hyphen as required, but when it is not required, there won't be a visible gap in the letters.

Answer (score 1):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a pre-process option, you could use the html tag `<wbr/>`, the word break. It does the same thing as the soft hyphen (`&shy;`), but without adding an *unsightly* hyphen when it breaks :) [here's a forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AF5Gn/) for you.

Just insert the tags after every underscore. In javascript:

```
str.replace(/_/, "_<wbr>");
```